# Why graph of +ve ax² open upwards and graph of -ve ax² open downwards?

Tags: quadratics, graphing-functions

While studying about quadratic equations i always wondered that why graph of +ve  ax² open upwards and graph of -ve ax² open downwards. I even asked my teacher but she just gave reason that because it does... And that makes no sense
If there's a quadratic equation ax²+bx+c then changing the value of a,b & c should affect the graph but I dont know how it affects the graph actually?
I mean what is the significance of value of c in graph similarly of a and b?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does open upwards & downwards mean?

Comment: I was asking why graph -ve ax² open downwards( the parabola opens downward) and why +ve ax² graph open upward
How the changing of the value of a, b & c affect the graph

Comment: Are positive and negative so hard to type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $ax^2$ term dominates as $x \to \infty$.  If $a$ is positive the graph will go to $+\infty$ and open upwards.  If $a$ is negative the graph will go to $-\infty$ and open downwards.  $c$ shifts the graph upwards or downwards.  $\frac b {2a}$ is the $x$ position of the vertex, so shifts the graph left or right.